# Observer doesn't call update method

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

Hey there I have a MVC Java Applcation which uses the observer pattern to notify my view on every change. 
I have a starter class to initialize all classes and set up everything for my MVC pattern.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        FXView view = new FXView();
        JSONModel model = new JSONModel();
        model.addObserver(view);
        Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);
        view.registerController(controller);
        FXView.launch(FXView.class);
}
```

I have a Model which does extend from Observable and has a method to write a file. There I want to call `setChanged()` and `notifyObserver()`.

```
public void writeFile() {
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C://path/to/file.json");
            file.write(obj.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(obj);
}
```

Every time the file gets written I want my view to know about it. My view does implement `Observer` and has therefore the `update()`method.

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    JSONModel model = (JSONModel)o;
    this.obj = model.getObj();
}
```

Using the debugger I could not detect an invoking of my update method. <s>When I start the program</s> `-->` when I go to my Starter class and call "Run as Java Application", my model loads a default value and then calls `writeFile()`. The file gets created and `setChanged()` as well as `notifyObserver()` gets called but `update()` won't be invoked. Is there something I miss out?

Comment: How the "notifyObservers" method looks like?

Comment: Just the standart method call from `java.util.Observable`, nothing I've written on my own.

Comment: "When I start the program" ... that means inside the model's constructor? ... Which is executed before you add the observer? You could try and give the JSONModel a Constructor where you can give it an observer. Then inside the ctor first add the observer, then do the rest of the initilziation.

Comment: Sorry wrote it unclear. But I think you have a point there. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Fildor solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, the call to notifyOberservers during the startup-phase is done before the Oberserver is added.

This can be solved by creating a Contructor that takes and adds an Oberserver first, before calling update.

Another approach would be an empty constructor and moving the init code to a different method. So you can call addObserver after creating the instance and then call the initialization method.

Personally, I'd go for the first one, because we do not want to be able to create instances that are uninitialized (= undefined state).